How to create a file geodatabase (.gdb) in Python without ArcPy?
I want to make a file geodatabase (.gdb) with GeoPandas and Fiona, but as long as I know there is no way to make a feature class without using ArcPy. Is there a way to make it?

GDAL driver 'ESRI File Geodatabase' has a create ability https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html#dataset-creation-options

You can create one by writing any GeoPandas dataframe to it:
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, MultiPolygon
out_db = r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/fgdb.gdb"

#Create some geometries
pnt = Point(1,1)
line = LineString([pnt, Point(1,2)])
polygon = MultiPolygon([pnt.buffer(distance=1)])

for layername, geom in zip(["Pointfc", "Linefc", "Polygonfc"], [pnt, line, polygon]):
    df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[geom], crs="EPSG:3006")
    df.to_file(filename=out_db, layer=layername, driver='OpenFileGDB')


